# IE7 don't understand floating width?

Tags: css, css-float

I don't know how to explain it,It was occurred in IE7 when the Right's DIV floatting right and unset the it's width,the floated left child DIV will become as width as it's parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/dyvar/1/

IE 7
[image]

Comment: If it's possible for you - add a `width` property to the floated parent with the class of `right`. It will help the layout look the same in ALL the browsers. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/dyvar/8/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
http://jsfiddle.net/dyvar/2/

```
<div class="right fr">
        <div class="fl">D1</div>
        <div class="fl">D2</div>
    </div>
```

I have update your html

previous html

```
<div class="right fr">
            <div class="fl">D1</div>
            <div class="fr">D2</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: i have update the previous html as well.Float right was there

Comment: you have to improve the code otherwise how can you achive you target.You html was wrong so i did in a right way.Class was wrong

Comment: @SACHIN by "what was wrong" I mean to ask why din't it work. :-)

Comment: ahhh..actully  <div class="fr">D2</div> is float:right and parent div is already float:right so that was the confict.

Comment: @SACHIN thanks, n y din't the conflit din't occur in other browsers??

Comment: because ie7 is the old browser :-) there are 1000s of question  FOR MR.bill gates regarding the ie bugs :-)